# Wait until element doesn't exists using PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait, page-factory, expected-condition

I'm trying to use only PageFactory in my project, without using fields with type By. And I'm looking to implement something like this:

```
@FindBy(className = "loading-container")
private WebElement loadingElement;

public LoadingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 20);
}

public void waitLoadingToFinish() {
    this.waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.elementNotExists(loadingElement));
}
```

Is there a way to implemet custom Expected Condition for this? or any other way to implement this? (without using By fields, only using page factory).

Comment: Which language bindings? Java?

Comment: yes I use java in my project

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have some elements on the page that you consider ready for usage only when there is no certain element on the page (like waiting wheel).

There is a special locator class in Selenium called `AjaxElementLocator`. What you need to do is to extend that type by changing `isElementUsable` method when you initialize your page so that all the controls you use on that page would first check the condition. Here is the example:

```java
package click.webelement.pagefactory.conditions;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocator;

public class LoadablePage {

    @FindBy(id = "cntrl-id")
    WebElement control;

    public LoadablePage(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(field -> new AjaxElementLocator(driver, field, 10){
            @Override
            protected boolean isElementUsable(WebElement element) {
                return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//WHEEL_XPATH")).size() == 0;
            }
        }, this);
    }

}
```

Here you can find [more information](https://webelement.click/en/selenium_page_object_expected_conditions) on such approach.

Comment: Interesting approach, I will look it up. Thank You!

Comment: this approach can help with the loading, but I have other places where I need to check if the element exists. Right now I'm using By fields for those specific elements ( and then findelements.size() != 0) and FindBy annotation for elements I know they exist. Is there a way to check existence for elements for FindBy annotation aswell? Thank You!

Comment: I think you need to rise new question with new piece of code example and new description so that we could look at this new issue closer

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has this method

> ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated
>
> An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not
> present on the DOM.

For your code

```
public void waitLoadingToFinish() {
    this.waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadingElement));
}
```

also, you might try to add a javascript executor to wait until the page is loaded

```
public static void waitForScriptsToLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}
```

and then your page constructor becomes this

```
public LoadingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    this.waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 20);
    waitForScriptsToLoad(driver);
}
```

Comment: But this function expects a locator. I'm looking for implementation using PageFactory

Comment: are you sure you understood what PageFactory is and how to use it?

Comment: yes, I can't implement this wait with using the FindBy annotation

Comment: Updated my answer see if that helps you

Comment: Nope - in this way you are forcing to wait until the entire page is loaded / and elements

Answer (score 0):

```
If you create wait method in your program that is easy and customize in selenium framework 

 private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }


//If you want wait for id  following code should use 

waitForElement(By.id(""),20);
Here 20 is miliseconds
```

and you can use any web elements to wait

Comment: I still need to use a locator instead of using the FindBy annotation

Answer (score 0):

To simulate an [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) like `elementNotExists` you can use either among `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` or `invisibilityOf()`.

---

### invisibilityOfElementLocated()

[invisibilityOfElementLocated()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is the implementation for an expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM. It is defined as follows:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.

Parameters:
    locator - used to find the element

Returns:
    true if the element is not displayed or the element doesn't exist or stale element
```

- Code Block:

  ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class fooPage {

        WebDriver driver;
        public fooPage(WebDriver driver)
        {
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

        //you don't need this
        //@FindBy(className = "loading-container")
        //private WebElement loadingElement;

        public void foo()
        {
            Boolean bool = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className('loading-container')));
            //other lines of code
        }
    }
  ```

---

As an alternative you can also use the `invisibilityOf()` method as follows:

### invisibilityOf()

[invisibilityOf()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) is the implementation for an expectation for checking the element to be invisible. It is defined as follows:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOf(WebElement element)
An expectation for checking the element to be invisible

Parameters:
    element - used to check its invisibility

Returns:
    Boolean true when elements is not visible anymore
```

- Code Block:

  ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class fooPage {

        WebDriver driver;
        public fooPage(WebDriver driver)
        {
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }


        @FindBy(className= 'loading-container')
        WebElement loadingElement;

        public void foo()
        {
            Boolean bool = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(fooPage.getWebElement()));
            //other lines of code
        }

        public WebElement getWebElement()
        {
            return loadingElement;
        }
    }
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to use explicit waits with PageFactory fields and the PageObject pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7AGczMaV578)